# PHP - Send Username in the email

Tags: php, email

I have a php code that works fine. I want to send an email to the admin saying `user - A` has made an request. When I check the email, it shows `user -`. It does not show the username.

THE PHP CODE:

```
<?php
     require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
     $username = $_SESSION ["username"];

 function leave_mail($user, $message){

    //Some connection and credentials for the gmail

     $username = $_SESSION ["username"];    
     $mail = new PHPMailer;

   leave_mail($username, "Your message has been sent to the <b>admin.</b>");
   leave_mail('amberTAG.adm@gmail.com', 'This message is to notify that you have a <b>new leave request</b> from <i><b>USER - <?php echo $username;?></b></i>');    
?>
```

Please help!

Comment: Hey it is not a valid code!

Comment: I didn't understand!?

Comment: You are already in PHP, concatenate.

Comment: If anyone **found it useful.** **Please upvote the question**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
leave_mail('amberTAG.adm@gmail.com', 'This message is to notify that you have a <b>new leave request</b> from <i><b>USER - ' . $username . '</b></i>');
```

That is because what you are writing is already php code. So `'xxx' . $username . 'yyy'` is a `string concat` in php.

When to use `<?php xxx; ?>`? When you are writing a `.php` file, you are defaultly writing html code. So when you want to write php, use it.

Example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>hello i am html</div>
<?php for($i=0;$i<5;++$i)echo 'Hey this is php code'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is already accepted. I just formatted the code block. There still needs a text explanation of the code. (Not my DV).

Comment: @chris85 explation edited. (But I wonder why there is a downvote as I have edited it...)